# c++ failed to probe dll

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2005, linker

I compiled a library in debug and release mode, both compilations are ok and generate me the 
.dll and the .lib.

If I compile and launch my application in release mode everything is ok, but if I launch in debug, the compliation is ok, but when the app is launching, this error comes to me:

> LDR: LdrpWalkImportDescriptor() failed
>   to probe c:\mydll_d.dll for its
>   manifest, ntstatus 0xc0150002
>   Debugger:: An unhandled
>   non-continuable exception was thrown
>   during process load The program '[260]
>   myProgram_d.exe: Native' has exited
>   with code -1072365566 (0xc0150002).

I read on the web that sometimes depends b the different version of visual studio...
I use the same version of visual studio ( vs2005 sp1 )

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you start it on the development machine, where VS2005 is installed or on a different PC when you get the error?